# Autocomplete de gems em editor de texto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, vim

Pessoal é possível obter uma experiência de autocomplete em algum editor de texto gratuito, similar ao que o Rubymine faz indexando o código das gems? Testei varias alternativas no vscode, como usar a cTag, mas apenas consigo ir para a definição da gem(abrindo outra tela), nada de autocomplete!

O vim possui tal recurso?

Comment: pro vscode tem o https://github.com/castwide/vscode-solargraph

Answer (score 0):

Todo o dinamismo do Ruby complicam o *autocomplete*. Tanto é que o rubistas são já acostumados a não ter uma ferramenta de *code completion* como tem o Java e o C#.

Quando não se há uma proficiência da linguagem ou da API, no seu caso as gems, que está trabalhando, o Vim acaba perdendo para as IDEs.

Ainda sim, existem algumas ferramentas que trazem o *autocomplete* para o Ruby, como é o caso do [Solargraph](https://github.com/castwide/solargraph). É só instalar a gem utilizando `gem install solargraph` e instalar o [plugin para o Vim](https://github.com/hackhowtofaq/vim-solargraph), que ainda está em beta. Tem também a extensão pra Visual Studio Code. É só ter a gem instalada no sistema.

Fica tudo ainda mais complicado quando você está utilizando Rails, que faz o *autoload* dos arquivos em tempo de execução. Muitas vezes o Solargraph não vê esse [`require`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require) e não consegue fazer o *autocomplete*.

Se estiver utilizando Docker, a gem deve estar instalada localmente, e não dentro do *container*.

Comment: vnbrs exatamente! Uso o solargraph no vscode e consigo apenas o complete do ruby mesmo e tinha visto essa questão do require! Tenho pouco tempo estudando rails, já tive contato com outra linguagens dinâmicas e ao que me parece outro fator que dificulta é os fato das gems ficarem na usr e não numa pasta vendor, como faz o laravel por exemplo. Desse modo os editores de texto não conseguem fazer indexação! Quanto ao vim, fiquei me perguntando porque o irb/pry consegue completar metodos do activerecords por exemplo?

Comment: O IRB e nem o Pry tem autocomplete do Rails. Somente o console do Rails, que carrega tudo e chama um REPL no contexto do Rails. Se não me engano tem um autocomplete, mas é bem fraco.

Comment: Exato! Acabei trocando. O jeito, por hora, vai ser desenvolver com o rails guide aberto!(e com a documentação das gems).

Comment: Vou te falar, as APIs do Rails são fáceis e muitas vezes você até adivinha como fazer as coisas! Com o Solargraph vc até consegue algum autocomplete do Active Record. Outra coisa e se apoiar na documentação e deixar um console do Rails aberto. 